# Как реализовать отправку данных в БД с форм выведенных циклом?

Tags: php, html, sql, веб-программирование

В БД имеются два справочника: "Подразделения", "Техника", отобразил я их так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На каждое подразделение выдается определенное количество техники которое пользователи должны указать сами, ввести в инпуты, введенные данные я хочу хранить в третьем справочнике "Справочник_норм", со столбцами ID_подразделения, ID_техники, Количество_техники. Как мне передавать данные из форм, которые выведены циклом ?

Код:

```
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h4>Нормы положенности: <?php echo $_SESSION['person']['nameovdrb'] ?></h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<?php if (!empty($resselect)) {
    foreach ($resselect as $ressub) { ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <table id="table-info" class="table table-sm  table-bordered" style="font-size: 12px;">
                    <thead class="bg-primary text-white text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan=9><?php echo $ressub->name_subdivision; ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="table-light text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <?php if (!empty($resselecttech)) {
                                foreach ($resselecttech as $restech) { ?>
                                    <td><?php echo $restech->type; ?></td>

                                <?php
                                } ?>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=9>В БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ НЕТ ЗАПИСЕЙ</td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <?php if (!empty($resselecttech)) {
                            foreach ($resselecttech as $restech) { ?>
                                <td><input required type="text"><span>единиц техники</span></td>
                            <?php
                            } ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=9>В БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ НЕТ ЗАПИСЕЙ</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=9><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Сохранить</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php
                } ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=9>В БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ НЕТ ЗАПИСЕЙ</td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<td><input required type="text"><span>единиц техники</span></td>`

тут надо добавить поле name для input-a и добавить ему квадратные ковычки ( получится массив )

`<td><input required type="text" name="inputname[]"><span>единиц техники</span></td>`

потом когда отправляешь форму получаешь

$_POST['inputname'][]

и его перебрать через php

```
foreach($_POST['inputname'] as $inpname){
   тут код 
}
```